# What is the deal with the console?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I apologize in advance for any vagueness, but I am so new to this. That being said, here is the issue:

I am using input validation for the first time with regex and am getting the following error in the console. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined." This is for line 6 of my JS. When I look at the code and compare line 6 to 16, they look exactly the same. Would someone please explain what I am doing wrong?

This is my first project and I would like for it to be error free. Please help, gently.

Thanks.

HTML:

```
    <input type="text" placeholder="Weight" id="userWeight" 
    onkeyup="numbersOnly(this)"/>

AND

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Dish" name="search" 
    id="mealText" onkeyup="lettersOnly(this)"/>

JS:
```

/*Function uses regular expression, which is a sequence of characters that define a search pattern. This pattern is used by string searching algorithms for "find" or "find and replace" operations on strings, or for input validation.
g = global; which is a flag that indicates the regular expression should be tested against all possible matches in a string & i = non-case sensitive
[] contains the regular expression logic that groups 'a' through 'z' and excludes all other characters using ^ = everything except*/

```
    function lettersOnly(input) {
      var regex = /[^a-z]/gi;
      input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "") //this is line 6 w/ 
      the error
      }
      lettersOnly();

    function numbersOnly(input) {
      var regex = /[^0-9]/g;
      input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "") //this is line 16 w/o 
      an error
      }
      }
      numbersOnly();
```

I tried removing the ';', and that did not work. Really am lost here.

The code functions as expected, but this error...

Comment: Because you're calling `lettersOnly();` and `numbersOnly();`, with no parameters, but the functions *expect* (and require) a parameter, the `input` element

Comment: I'm not sure what argument to pass in to the function call. The video that I watched shows this code exactly as I have it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpajusnOfYo&t=214s

Comment: @KingdomB the video doesn't have the `lettersOnly()` call you've put on line 9. Your code fails, because you've added that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code,you arr calling `lettersOnly()` and `numbersOnly()` in JS code

remove this calls from JS code as your calling this function from HTML on key up event

```
function lettersOnly(input) {
  var regex = /[^a-z]/gi;
  input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "") //this is line 6 w/ 

  }

function numbersOnly(input) {
  var regex = /[^0-9]/g;
  input.value = input.value.replace(regex, "") //this is line 16 w/o 

  }
```